# Change workspace directory in Visual Studio Code

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, workspace

Is it possible to change the default workspace directory `.vscode` from Visual Studio Code under Windows? There are always vscode related directories e.g. `.vscode`, `.tools` created in the home directory of my user account `C:\Users\Foo\.vscode`.

Is it possible to change this behaviour? I've already looked in the `settings.json`, but wasn't successfull in finding the correct spot of change.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I´ve found this unanswered question because I´ve been searching for a solution to move my workspace to another disk.
One possible solution that It´s working for me is to open workspace file with a text editor.
This should look similar to this:

```
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "..\\folderA\\folderB"
        }
    ],
    "settings": {}
}
```

The only thing that you should do to change workspace working folder it´s to change the "path" to your new working directory.

Note: This it´s working for me because what I have on my new working forlder it´s a clone from the original one, but if it´s not the case I guess that you should be careful about some configurations that you have done in your original path, because it´s possible that there are some elements on there (mainly related to extensions and so) that should be coppied in order to get the new path working perfectly.

Hope it helps.